# NewRelic sqlite instrumentation error

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, newrelic

Newrelic is showing instrumentation errors in logs. They don't affect the server, but it seems impossible to get rid of them.

```
[2015-05-11 14:13:48,236] newrelic.config:764 ERROR INSTRUMENTATION ERROR
[2015-05-11 14:13:48,236] newrelic.config:765 ERROR Type = import-hook
[2015-05-11 14:13:48,237] newrelic.config:766 ERROR Locals = {'function': 'instrument_sqlite3', 'instrumented': set([('newrelic.hooks.database_sqlite', 'instrument_sqlite3')]), 'target': <module 'pysqlite2' from '[......]/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysqlite2/__init__.pyc'>, 'module': 'newrelic.hooks.database_sqlite'}
[2015-05-11 14:13:48,237] newrelic.config:767 ERROR Exception Details
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[......]/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.50.0.39/newrelic/config.py", line 801, in _instrument
    function)(target)
  File "[......]/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-2.50.0.39/newrelic/hooks/database_sqlite.py", line 98, in instrument_sqlite3
    if not isinstance(module.connect, ConnectionFactory):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'
```

Looks like it shows up whenever a sqlite database is opened. Any ideas on this?